# How do I create radio buttons in jquery mobile and call a url from them

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I want to make radio buttons in jquery mobile that aren't input fields. Instead I would like to direct the user to a new page. How do I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
    <input name="compose" type="radio" value="1" id="compose"/>
    <label for="compose">Compose</label>
    <input name="index" type="radio" value="2" id="inbox"/>
    <label for="inbox">Inbox</label>
</fieldset>
```

I would like to direct the user to a website when one of these is selected.

Comment: So.. you haven't tried anything?

Comment: I tried to use jquery and set up an onChange event without any success

Comment: Show us that.  At present, it seems like you're asking us to do work for you without any prior attempts.

Comment: Use this `$(document).on('click', '[type=radio]', function () { $.mobile.changePage('#'+ $(this).attr('id')); });` assuming that `id` is the page. For URL, add it as an attribute and use `$.mobile.changePage` as well.

Comment: Here is a demo http://fiddle.jshell.net/pLSBK/

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, your radio buttons won't behave as such unless they have the same name... but I guess it doesn't matter since the user will be redirected right away.

As for your question, you can't make them "not be an input field", because a radio button IS an input field by definition. Now, to redirect your user when one is selected, you don't necessarily need Jquery. With simple Javascript (which is easier on the system, thus more advantageous), you can do:

```
[select your element].onclick=function() {
window.location="your_new_URL";
}
```

With Jquery, it can be done too, of course.

```
$('#yourID').click(function() {
window.location="your_new_URL";
});
```